# what is best practice? An attribute or an Entity?

Tags: c#, database-design, relational-database

I'm trying to build a person directory database, where the person has many entities such as Address, Phone, as well as Email and Notes.
but I want/try to implement 'Email' and 'Notes' as attributes of the 'Person' class instead of separate entities.

I would appreciate some help in understanding how I would achieve this with attribute?
Which one of these two options are a better practice?

I have to add that a person should/could have many email addresses as well as Notes.

Here is my person class:

```
    public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.PrimaryAddress = new Address();
        this.AlternativeAddresses = new List<AlternativeAddress>();
        this.TelefonNumbers = new List<Telefon>();
    }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual List<AlternativeAddress> AlternativeAddresses { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Telefon> TelefonNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What you have now looks perfect, you want something like anonymous types for the properties? That doesn't seem like a better approach.

Comment: Is your question related to the object model (the c# implementation) or to the database design/modeling (how tables will relate in the RDBMS)?

Comment: Primarily, the question is about the implementation. Secondly, about the design of RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same approach as you used at

`public virtual List<AlternativeAddress> AlternativeAddresses { get; set; }`

with

`public virtual List<string> EmailAdresses { get; set; }`

or

`public virtual List<EmailEntity> EmailAdresses { get; set; }`

both would be perfectly fine. It only depends on your likings and type of operations, you have to perform later on.

Comment: Thanks. I think public virtual List<string> EmailAdresses { get; set; } is what I was looking for.